# Faster option than glmnet for elastic net regularized regression

Tags: r, regression, glmnet, model-evaluation, elastic-net

I attempted to predict crime category from its X and Y coordinates based on San Francisco Crime Statistics (https://www.kaggle.com/c/sf-crime). And it turned out that glmnet is pretty slow for fitting on this dataset: when I fit on a sample of 100k observations, it takes about 3 minutes. If I extrapolate that time to the whole dataset (878k observations) - the whole fit will take about 25 minutes.

So, my questions are

1. What is the maximum data set size to work in R **interactively**?
2. How faster would be other languages (Python, Java) on the similar task?
3. Does such performance mean that I should not at all attempt at all to solve such a big problem in R and choose instead other language?

Comment: Also as a comment: "interactively" depends on your data, on what you do, your PC, your standards, your operating system, on how many other apps are you running simultaneously and in the background etc.

Comment: Other languages won't speed up this particular analysis very much if at all because glmnet is not coded in R (I think its in Fortran).

Comment: @Tim this question is about choosing a right tool for analysis, so I believe it may be useful to other users as well

Comment: There is also github.com/simonster/Lasso.jl, which offers a faster implementation of glmnet in Julia, code.google.com/archive/p/lasso4j/source/default/source which offers a Java implementation of glmnet and github.com/mchrzanowski/improved_glmnet, which has a C++ implementation - you could try any of these to see if they might be faster... For a high n, low p setting (high nr of obs, low nr of variables) you could also try the oem R package, which is faster than glmnet for that setting...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have a good idea that you can get a feel for things with a smaller sample, to work out the kinks in your approach. And it's definitely true, as you've noticed, that things that take a while to run really break up your focus. It's annoying. But...

Second, you have to define "interactively". Do you mean instantaneously, 1 second, 10 seconds, or what?

Third, you need to account for your hardware, the software you're using, how much data you have, and what algorithm you're executing.

For example, doing an `lm` on 100K rows of data might be "interactive" for you. Obviously `glmnet` is doing a *lot* more than that.

In terms of other languages, Python or Java may be faster if you have a lot of code outside of `glmnet` that you're executing. As one of the comments says, `glmnet` is coded in C or Fortran and will be as fast as possible. If you're doing looping or a lot of code around your `glmnet`, it's easier in R to do something inefficient than it is in programming languages not designed for statistics like Python or Java.

It's possible to parallelize some algorithms. I'm not sure if `glmnet` is one of them. If you find a language that has a parallelized version -- say one that uses multiple cores, and you're running on a machine with multiple cores and enough RAM -- that will speed things up sub-linearly. Four cores won't be four times as fast, but it should be 2-3x faster.

So, the answer is "no, probably not". Your algorithm will usually trump anything else, and perhaps `glmnet` alone isn't the best option.

Comment: For the record, GLMNET has parallel capability, but only if you're running it in a CV-type setting, i.e. fitting $k$ glmnet models at a time.

Answer (score 7):

Following @Wayne's comments on parallelization, see [Zhou et al. (2014), "A Reduction of the Elastic Net to Support Vector Machines with an Application to GPU Computing", arXiv:1409.1976](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1976). They say

> The state-of-the-art single-core implementation for solving the
>   Elastic Net problem is the glmnet package developed by Friedman.
>   Mostly written in Fortran language, glmnet adopts the coordinate
>   gradient descent strategy and is highly optimized. As far as we know,
>   it is the fastest off-the-shelf solver for the Elastic Net. Due to its
>   inherent sequential nature, the coordinate descent algorithm is
>   extremely hard to parallelize.

but come up with a different approach, showing the elastic net is equivalent a type of support vector machine (which can be parallelized):

> [...] we take inspiration from recent work on machine learning
>   reductions [15, 19] and we reduce the Elastic Net to the squared
>   hinge-loss SVM (without a bias term). We show that this reduction is
>   exact and extremely efficient in practice. The resulting algorithm,
>   which we refer to as Support Vector Elastic Net (SVEN), naturally
>   takes advantage of the vast existing work on parallel SVMs,
>   immediately providing highly efficient Elastic Net and Lasso
>   implementations on GPUs, multi-core CPUs and distributed systems

Note that hyper-parameter selection by cross-validation can of course be parallelized (and is implemented for the shrinkage hyper-parameter in `cv.glmnet`—see [executing glmnet in parallel in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21698435/1864816)).

The Matlab code to fit a Support Vector Elastic Net is available at https://bitbucket.org/mlcircus/sven/. You could give that a try!

Comment: Only thing is that the Support Vector Elastic Net cannot take into account positivity or box constraints, which in many applications you need, whereas glmnet does...

Comment: There is also https://github.com/simonster/Lasso.jl, which offers a faster implementation of glmnet in Julia, code.google.com/archive/p/lasso4j/source/default/source which offers a Java implementation of glmnet and github.com/mchrzanowski/improved_glmnet, which has a C++ implementation - you could try any of these to see if they might be faster... For a high n, low p setting (high nr of obs, low nr of variables) you could also try the oem R package, which is faster than glmnet for that setting...